# Is it correct to introduce myself on the phone by saying "I'm ..."

Tags: conversation

It's common that I always hear people on the phone would say

> Hello, This is Alex, is that Brenda?

I wonder whether when I substitute "This is" with "I am" is correct. Also substituting "is that" with "are you".

Is it just because of naturality thing, so that I won't sound awkward when I follow this format? Let's say I'm in a video call, I actually see the person on my phone screen. Do we still say "This is..." and "Is that..."? The third case, what if it's a video call/meeting, but the person is not showing her face.

Comment: No, I am Alex is a mistake here. Only in Spanish: Soy Alex.

Comment: "**Is that** Brenda?" does not sound natural to me as a US English speaker.  I would say "Is *this* Brenda?" or "Am I speaking to Brenda?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When *introducing yourself* to someone for the first time, whether on the phone, on a video call or in person, it's most common to say, "I'm _________." A more formal way of introducing yourself in all of those situations is, "My name is ________".

When you *announce* yourself to someone on the phone who already knows you, or knows the place you're calling from, it's most common to say, "It's __________", or more formally, "This is ___________".

> Alison: Hello?
> Bob: Hey Alison, **it's** Bob.
> OR
> Bob: Hello Alison, **this is** Bob from Downtown Pharmacy.

With video and in person we don't say anything like this because we expect people we know to see us and recognize us even before we speak. If there's a chance they've forgotten our name, then we introduce ourselves again with "I'm _______" or "My name is _______".